# Кирилица в javasript

Tags: jquery, javascript

Пишу такую фигню:

```
function mailSend(id){
var mailPanel=$("<div id='mailpanel'></div>");
$.post("index.php",{mod: "mail", id: id, do: "mail", popUp: "AJAX"},     function(htm){
    mailPanel.append("sd f влдоапиваоли");

    mailPanel.dialog({
        title:  "Смена пароля",
        width:  550,
        close: function(){
                mailPanel.dialog("destroy");
        }
    });
});
}
```

Там где кириллица, показывает вопросики. Как с этим быть? Кодировка сайта в `windows-1251`, и файл редактируется в `windows-1251`.

Comment: на кофейной гуще не гадаем. Живой пример фстудию.

Comment: А что конкретно показать? скрин? Помоему результат этой функции очевиден... title диалогово окна вопросиками показывает, и тело тоже...

Answer (score 1):

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
или curl в консоле и посмотреть ответ. кодировку в заголовке

Answer (score 0):

В общем-то, вы сами определили причину - это кодировка windows-1251. 
[Почитайте об этом тут](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/webdev/17640/) и [это тоже](http://blog.itcross.net/2007/11/23/ajax-i-kodirovka-zaprosov/) может помочь

Comment: Так сайт ведь на кириллице... и к яаксу это не относится... кирилица загружается вместе с исходником, а не аяксом.